# Title tags using jquery not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

i am trying to add the title tag from post title to all images within a div.
 So i have added this jquery script to my website

```
$(window).load(function() {
posttitle = $(".postwr").find("h1.title").text().trim();
$(".post img").each(function() {
$(this).attr("title", posttitle)
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="postwr">
<h1 class="title">Title tags using jquery not working in IE8</h1>
<div class="post">
<img src="image.png"/>
</div></div>
```

It works fine in chrome, ie7, firefox, but when hovering the image in ie8, the title didn't appear, i don't know why.
Hope for your helps

Comment: why so many `.parent()` calls

Comment: Is the title attribute present in IE8? Or not at all?

Comment: Try setting **alt** attribute for <img> tags